# Protecting some properties of an entity from modification

Tags: php, symfony, orm, crud, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony 3 app that uses Doctrine ORM for Entity management. Currently, I am working on enabling CRUD support. I've already found out that I can use [security voters](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/voters.html) to restrict access to entities or controllers. For example, I configured it the way that only admins can create, update or delete entities of type A.

For instances of my entity type B I also want to give the respective owner the power to update (not create or delete), which I managed to do easily. However, an owner shouldn't be allowed to modify all of the entity's properties - just some of them. How can I realize this with Symfony? Also, I am using the Form Bundle to create and validate forms.

**EDIT:** I added some related code. The controller invokes `denyAccessUnlessGranted`, which triggers the voter. Just to clarify, that code works fine already. My question is related to code I don't yet have.

**Controller:**

```
public function editAction(Request $request, int $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $project = $em->getRepository(Project::class)->findOneBy(['id'=>$id]);

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(ProjectVoter::EDIT, $project);

    $users = $em->getRepository(EntityUser::class)->findAll();
    $groups = $em->getRepository(Group::class)->findAll();
    $tags = $em->getRepository(Tag::class)->findAll();

    $form = $this->createForm(ProjectType::class, $project, [
        'possibleAdmins' => $users,
        'possibleRequiredGroups' => $groups,
        'possibleTags' => $tags,
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $project = $form->getData();
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('projects_show', ['id'=>$project->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('project/editor.html.twig',
        ['project'=>$project, 'form'=>$form->createView()]);
}
```

**Voter:**

```
protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token) {

    /** @var UserInterface $user */
    $user = $token->getUser();

    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        // the user must be logged in; if not, deny access
        return false;
    }
    else if ($this->decisionManager->decide($token, ['ROLE_ADMIN'])) {
        return true; // system-wide admins shall always have access
    }

    switch($attribute) {

        case self::SHOW:
            return  ($subject->isVisible() || $subject->getAdmins()->contains($user);

        case self::EDIT:
            return $subject->getAdmins()->contains($user);

        case self::REMOVE:
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: To be more clear you should add the related code you already have so we can give a specific solution based on it.

Comment: @gp_sflover Yeah, should have done this in the first place. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution in the end:

Instead of having multiple `FormType`s I stuck with only a single one and ended up enabling or disabling the property's form field based on the result of the voter. For that I defined a new switch case as Cerad suggested (named `ProjectVoter::MODIFY_PROTECTED_PROPERTY` in this answer for demonstration purposes) and added the business logic per my liking.

I just enabled or disabled the form field because I actually want the user to see that he/she can't edit that property. But it would likely easily be possible to not `add` the field in the first place as well, so it's not visible.

**Form Type:**

*Info: `$this->tokenStorage` and `$this->accessDecisionManager` are injected services (`"security.token_storage"` and `"security.access.decision_manager"` respectively).*

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $token = $options['token'] ?? $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

    $project = $builder->getData();

    $builder
        ->add('name')

        // ...

        ->add('protectedProperty', null, [
            'disabled' => !$this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, [ProjectVoter::MODIFY_PROTECTED_PROPERTY], $project),
        ])
    ;
}
```

I also added an option to the form type called `token` in its `configureOptions` function which defaults to `null`, so that the form can be built for an arbitrary user instead of the one currently logged-in, if required.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no access functionality specifically related to individual properties.  Of course as soon as I post this, someone else will come by with exactly that.

What you might consider doing is to define two edit roles, EDIT_BY_ADMIN and EDIT_BY_OWNER.  You could then test the condition and select which form type to use.

```
$projectTypeClass = null;
if ($this->isGranted(ProjectVoter::EDIT_BY_ADMIN,$project)) {
    $projectTypeClass = ProjectAdminType::class);
}
elseif ($this->isGranted(ProjectVoter::EDIT_BY_OWNER,$project)) {
    $projectTypeClass = ProjectOwnerType::class);
}
if (!$projectTypeClass) {
    // throw access denied exception
}
$form = $this->createForm($projectTypeClass, $project, [
```

And that should do the trick.  There are of course many variations.  You could stick with one project type and do the access testing within the type class though that would require a form listener.

If you need more granularity then you could instead add some EDIT_PROP1, EDIT_PROP2 type roles.

And of course if you were really into it then you could move some of the access code into a database of some sort.  Or maybe take a look at some of the Access Control List components out there.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it really helped! See my answer if you want to see what I ended up doing.